# How to remove control characters in a delimited file?

Tags: bash, unix

I am just wondering what is the best way to remove control characters from a delimited file using sed/awk in bash. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the character class `[:cntrl:]` with GNU `sed`:

```
sed 's/[[:cntrl:]]//g' file.txt
```

From [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html):

> ‘[:cntrl:]’
>
> Control characters. In ASCII, these characters have octal codes 000 through 037, and 177 (DEL). In other character sets, these are the equivalent characters, if any.